# Actual colour codes VS changing Alpha value for fonts

Tags: usability, user-behavior, design, ux-field

Is there any advantage in using one against the other. Material design guidelines have used Alpha values to signify contrast for fonts. I could not really find a reason for doing so(as compared to using absolute colour values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**When using an alpha value, the color you see depends on the color in the layer below the color with alpha value.**

See the example below.

When using a black (#000000) with 50 alpha on a white background you will get the 'actual color code' #7F7F7F, but when you but a blue color behind it, it will influence the actual color code of the #000000 with 50 alpha. In that case it is #277160.

Developers (the ones I've worked with) prefer actual color codes because of this.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Material design guidelines use opacity for readability and accessibility reasons. The example they use on https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-usability demonstrates the issue:

[image: Using opacity instead of shifting colors often creates better contrast and relative luminance.]